# How to find blob in tree by its name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, grit

I have a tree of commit found by SHA-1,code is:
tree = repo.tree(sha)
now I need to find blob by file name and display its content

Answer (score 1):

given the SHA1 of the commit itself, you would:

```
git show SHA1:path/to/your/file.txt
```

if you know the sha1 of the blob itself, you can

```
git cat-file blob SHA1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, and do you know ho to do same in ruby ob rails?

Comment: I'm not sure about RoR, but check to see if the repo object has some methods that would allow you to get the blob contents by a SHA1 reference..